# How to update Enterprise Keywords column in SPFx WebPart or Extension using PnPJs

Tags: spfx, managed-metadata, pnp, spfx-extensions, enterprise-keywords

How can I update the Enterprise Keywords column of a SharePoint document library using PnPjs in a SharePoint Framework (SPFx) Web Part or Extension.
How can I design a user-friendly user interface (UI) component within an SPFx Web Part or Extension to efficiently manage and edit the Enterprise Keywords field in SharePoint